# Populate dropdown django modelform

Tags: python, django, dynamic, drop-down-menu, populate

**forms.py**:

```
class BetaUser(ModelForm):
    Industry = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = homepagelaunch_industries.objects.all(), initial=1)
        class Meta:
            model = BetaUsers
            fields = ['Industry']
```

**model.py**

```
class BetaUsers(models.Model):
    Industry = models.CharField(verbose_name="Industry",max_length=100)
    #Industry = forms.ModelChoiceField(verbose_name="Industry", queryset=Indus.objects.all())

class Industries(models.Model):
    IndustryChoice = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

**view.py**

```
def BetaUserDisplayForm(request):
    BetaUserGatherForm = BetaUser(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if BetaUserGatherForm.is_valid():
            BetaUserIndustry = BetaUserGatherForm.cleaned_data['Industry']
            BetaUserGatherForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/BetaUserThankYou/')
            except:
                raise ('Invalid request')
        else:
            BetaUserGatherForm = BetaUser()

    return render(request, 'apage.html', {
        'BetaUserGatherForm': BetaUserGatherForm
    })
```

I am simply trying to populate the value of `Industry` from the database column `IndustryChoice` from the model class: `Industries` .
what am I doing wrong? Can someone help?

Im getting error:

```
name 'homepagelaunch_industries' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue/error you are having?

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated question with the error

Comment: I think you have not imported your model `homepagelaunch_industries` in `forms.py`

Comment: I tried doing that, that didn't seem to fix it. It still gives me:   

`name 'homepagelaunch_industries' is not defined` . I updated my code above.

Comment: Can you post your `forms.py`?

Comment: Forms.py is "form" above.

Comment: Then you have not imported `homepagelaunch_industries`